# What purpose does counts serve? Line 7

Tags: ruby, return-value

I am wondering what purpose does the counts variable serve, the one right before the last end?

```
# Pick axe page 51, chapter 4

# Count frequency method
def count_frequency(word_list)
    counts = Hash.new(0)
    for word in word_list
        counts[word] += 1
    end
    counts    #what does this variable actually do?
end

puts count_frequency(["sparky", "the", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat"])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last expression in any Ruby method is the return value for that method. If `counts` were not at the end of the method, the return value would be the result of the `for` loop; in this case, that's the `word_list` array itself:

```
irb(main):001:0> def count(words)
irb(main):002:1>   counts = Hash.new(0)
irb(main):003:1>   for word in words
irb(main):004:2>     counts[word] += 1
irb(main):005:2>   end
irb(main):006:1> end
#=> nil
irb(main):007:0> count %w[ sparky the cat sat on the mat ]
#=> ["sparky", "the", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat"]
```

Another way someone might write the same method in 1.9:

```
def count_frequency(word_list)
  Hash.new(0).tap do |counts|
    word_list.each{ |word| counts[word]+=1 }
  end
end
```

*Though some people consider using [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) like this to be an abuse. :)*

And, for fun, here's a slightly-slower-but-purely-functional version:

```
def count_frequency(word_list)
  Hash[ word_list.group_by(&:to_s).map{ |word,array| [word,array.length] } ]
end
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why the `counts` line was needed at the end of the method.

Comment: so it's similar to "return counts", right? If so, that's tricky for beginners but good to know.

Comment: @jimmyc3po Correct; in Ruby you _can_ put an explicit `return` anywhere in your method. It's not common, however. Instead, the result of the last expression is usually used as the return value.

Comment: @jimmyc3po That is right, and yes, it is a bit tricky for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby doesn't require you to use the `return` statement to return a value in a method.  The last line evaluated in the method will be returned if an explicit `return` statement is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

It provides the return value for the function; it's how the result (which is stored in that variable) is transmitted back to the caller (i.e., the line of code at the end.) The last expression evaluated in a Ruby function is used as the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Counts is a dictionary, i.e. it is an associative map of keys to values.

In this case, the words are the keys, the values are the number of occurrences.

The dictionary is returned from the *function* `count_frequency`